# Getting File Version Custom Fields

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, office365-rest-client

I hope someone can help. I'm stuck in getting the file version custom fields from the sharepoint rest api. I tried to do expand on:
ListItemAllFields
ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText
None of the above helped. Im able to do it on the file but not the file version.
Please help